# How to get all the values in one wrapping circle in swimlane-ngx-charts - gauge chart

Tags: angular, charts

I'm using the ngx swimlane charts (

```
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
```

) .

Here in the charts (
https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-gauge-chart?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts
), we see that the values wrap around each other in circles in different colours. I need all the values in the same circle, but divided into different colours. I don't want them to wrap around separately around each other. Is it doable in this library? if not which library can i use in angular 12

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the donut chart can be an alternative to what you need to visualize. https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/pie-charts/advanced-pie-chart